# How does \ifthesection of titleps work?

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, titleps

The [`titleps`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titleps?lang=en) documentation mentions:

> (Only `titlesec`. Not in `titleps`.) `\ifthechapter{⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}`, `\ifthesection{⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}`,`\ifthesubsection{⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}`... which expands to `⟨true⟩` except if the corresponding title lacks of label or there is no title yet after the superior level (for example, between `\chapter` and a subsequent `\section`).

Now, consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\settitlemarks{chapter,section,subsection}
\newpagestyle{myPageStyle}[\scshape]{
    \headrule
    \sethead
    [\thechapter][\MakeLowercase\chaptertitle][]  % even
    {} % odd
    {\MakeLowercase\subsectiontitle}
    {   \ifthesection{
            \S\ \thesection\ifthesubsection{
                .\thesubsection
            }{\normalfont [no subsec detected]}
        }{\normalfont [no sec detected]}
    }
}

\pagestyle{myPageStyle}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{Call me by your name}
    \lipsum[1-15]
        \section{Elio}
        \lipsum[1-8]
            \subsection{Bach}
            \lipsum[1]
            \subsection{Oliver}
            \subsection{Marzia}
\end{document}
```

The last page of the generated PDF looks like so:

[image]

This is confusing I expected `§1.1` since the first thing that appears on the page is a continuation from `\subsection{Bach}` (the first section).

On the other hand, I do get the following page in the PDF as expected:

[image]

This is explainable since the text that appears first on this page is contained in no subsection, only the section `\section{Elio}`.

**Question**. Can someone please explain what is going on? I can't seem to figure it out from the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is described in the manual (page 4):

> **5. Marks**
> Marks can be retrieved in 4 ways:
> **top marks** If a page begins with text, they are the marks belonging to the sectioning unit of that text. If a page begin with a sectioning title, they are the marks of that title. In other words, top marks
> refer to the section immediately adjacent to the headline.
> **first marks** The marks of the very first sectioning title.
> **botttom marks** The marks of the very last (bottom) sectioning title (also known as bot marks).
> **next top marks** A botttom mark with the values of the top mark of the next page (only straight class or equivalent); by picking some value from it and comparing it with the corresponding value from the botttom marks you may know if a section continues in the next page. Of course, it will not be
> used very often.

and then on page 5:

> `\bottitlemarks \toptitlemarks \firsttitlemarks \nexttoptitlemarks \outertitlemarks \innertitlemarks`
> These commands set which mark the values of the subsequent `\thesection`, `\sectiontitle`, etc., will be taken from.
> ...
> You can use them freely in your headers;

The default seems to be first marks. If you want to label the last page *BACH § 1.1* then you need top title marks:

```
\newpagestyle{myPageStyle}[\scshape]{
    \headrule
    \sethead
    [\thechapter][\MakeLowercase\chaptertitle][]  % even
    {} % odd
    {\toptitlemarks\MakeLowercase\subsectiontitle}
    {\toptitlemarks\ifthesection{
            \S\ \thesection\ifthesubsection{
                .\thesubsection
            }{\normalfont [no subsec detected]}
        }{\normalfont [no sec detected]}
    }
}
```

Or, simpler, as a package option:

```
\usepackage[pagestyles,topmarks]{titlesec}
```

Result:

[image]